# RedBlack tree deletion Algorithms

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

i am reading the book Introduction to Algorithms
in chapter red-black trees deletion section
they show me the code below

```
RB-DELETE(T,z)
1 y = z
2 y-original-color = y:color
3 if z.left == T.nil
4       x = z.right
5       RB-T RANSPLANT .T; ´; ´:right/
6 elseif z.right == T:nil
7       x =z.left
8       RB-T RANSPLANT (z,z.left)
9 else y = Minimum(z.right)
10      y-original-color = y.color
11      x = y.right
12      if y.p == z
13          x.p = y
14      else RB-TRANSPLANT (T,y,y.right)
15          y.right = z.right
16          y.right.p = y
17          RB-TRANSPLANT(T,z,y)
18      y.left = z.left
19      y.left:p = y
20      y.color = z.color
21if y-original-color == BLACK
22      RB-DELETE-Fix-Up(T,x)
```

this is the implementation in C++

```
void RedBlack::transplant(ColoredNode* destination, ColoredNode* source)
{
    if(destination->parent == centinel)
        this->root = source;
    else if(destination->parent->left == destination)
        destination->parent->left = source ;
    else
        destination->parent->right = source;
    source->parent = destination->parent;

}

void RedBlack::DeleteNode(ColoredNode* node)
{
    bool replacementColor = node->black;
    ColoredNode* replacement = node ;
    ColoredNode* repReplacement = node;

    if(node->left == this->centinel && node->right == this->centinel)
    {
        transplant(node , centinel); // IT CHANGES THE CENTINEL PARENT 
    }
    else if(node->left == centinel && node->right != centinel)
    {
        repReplacement = node->right;
        this->transplant(node,node->right);
    }
    else if(node->right == centinel && node->left != centinel)
    {
        repReplacement = node->left ;
        this->transplant(node,node->left);
    }
    else
    {
        replacement = this->successor(node);
        replacementColor = replacement->black;  // save the color of replacement ...
        repReplacement = replacement->right ;
        if(replacement == node->right)
            repReplacement->parent = replacement ;  
            // this line is in case of repRe** == centinel ,centinel->parent == null then the fixup function will fail cause we don't have any path to ancestors ...
        else
        {
            transplant(replacement,repReplacement);
            replacement->right = node->right;
            node->right->parent = replacement;
        }
        transplant(node,replacement);
        replacement->left = node->left;
        node->left->parent = replacement ;
        replacement->black = node->isBlack();
    }
    
    if(replacementColor)    // if the replacement is black ...
        this->DeleteNodeFixUp(repReplacement);

}
```

Also the deletion fixup Algorithm is :

```
RB-DELETE-FIXUP (T,x)
1 while x != T.root and x.color == BLACK
2       if x == x.p.left
3               w = x.p.right
4               if w.color == RED      // CASE 1
5                   w.color = BLACK
6                   x.p.color = RED
7                   LEFT-ROTATE(T,x.p)
8                   w D x.p.right

9               if w.left.color == BLACK and w.right.color == BLACK // CASE 2
10                  w.color = RED
11                  x = x.p
12              else if w.right.color == BLACK // CASE 3
13                  w.left.color D BLACK
14                  w.color D RED
15                  RIGHT-ROTATE(T,w) 
16                  w = x.p.right
17              w.color = x.p.color  //CASE 4
18              x.p.color = BLACK
19              w.right.color = BLACK
20              LEFT-ROTATE(T, x.p)
21              x = T.root
22      else (same as then clause with “right” and “left” exchanged)
23 x:color D BLACK
```

my C++ implementation is :

```
void RedBlack::DeleteNodeFixUp(ColoredNode* node)
{
        ColoredNode *parent = node->parent ;
        ColoredNode *sibling = this->centinel ;

        while( node != this->root && node->isBlack())
        {
            
            if(node == parent->left)
            {
                sibling = parent->right ;
                printf("node = %d , parent =%d ,sibling = %d \n",node->data,parent->data,sibling->data);
                if(sibling->isRed())
                {
                    printf("sibling is red\n");
                    parent->black = false;
                    sibling->black = true;
                    node->black = true ;
                    LeftRotation(parent);
                    sibling = parent->right;
                }
                    
                if(sibling->isBlack())
                {
                    // CASE 2 : SIBLING AND ITS CHILDREN ARE BLACK
                    if(sibling->right->isBlack() && sibling->left->isBlack())
                    {
                        sibling->black = false ;
                        node = parent ;
                        parent = node->parent;
                        if(node == parent->left)
                            sibling = parent->right;
                        else    
                            sibling = parent->left;
                        //continue;
                    }
                    else if(sibling->right->isBlack())//CASE 3 : SIBLING IS BLACK AND ITS RIGHT IS BLACK
                    {
                        sibling->black = false;
                        sibling->left->black = true;
                        RightRotation(sibling);
                        sibling = parent->right;
                    }
                }

                //CASE 4 : SIBLING IS BLACK AND SIBLING'S RIGHT IS RED
                sibling->right->black = true;
                sibling->black = false;
                parent->black = true;
                LeftRotation(parent);
                node = this->root;
            }
            else        // node is right child and sibling 
            {
                sibling = parent->left ;
                printf("node = %d , parent =%d ,sibling = %d \n",node->data,parent->data,sibling->data);
                if(sibling->isRed())
                {
                    parent->black = false;
                    sibling->black = true;
                    node->black = true ;
                    RightRotation(parent);
                    sibling = parent->left;
                }

                if(sibling->isBlack())
                {
                    // CASE 2 : SIBLING AND ITS CHILDREN ARE BLACK ...
                    if(sibling->left->isBlack() && sibling->right->isBlack())
                    {
                        sibling->black = false ;
                        node = parent ;
                        parent = node->parent;
                        
                        //continue;
                    }
                    else if(sibling->left->isBlack())//CASE 3 : SIBLING IS BLACK AND ITS LEFT IS BLACK
                    {
                        sibling->right->black = true;
                        sibling->black = false ;
                        RightRotation(sibling);
                        sibling = parent->left ;
                    }
                }

                sibling->left->black = true;
                //CASE 4 : SIBLING IS BLACK AND ITS LEFT IS RED
                sibling->black = false;
                parent->black = true;
                RightRotation(parent);
                node = this->root;
            }
        }

        
        node->black = BLACK_NODE ;
}
```

but when i test all that i find out that there is an error in fixup algorithms :
this is my tree

```
                    N
                              50|B
                                        N
                    35|R
                                        N
                              24|B
                                        N
          23|B
                                        N
                              21|B
                                        N
                    20|R
                                        N
                              19|B
                                        N
15|B
                              N
                    4|B
                                        N
                              2|R
                                        N
          1|B
                              N
                    -4|B
                                        N
                              -30|R
                                        N
```

when i delete 23 the resulting tree is

```
                              N
                    50|R
                              N
          35|R
                              N
                    24|B
                                                  N
                                        21|B
                                                  N
                              20|R
                                                  N
                                        19|B
                                                  N
15|B
                              N
                    4|B
                                        N
                              2|R
                                        N
          1|B
                              N
                    -4|B
                                        N
                              -30|R
                                        N
```

as you can see 35 and 50 violate third rule (each red node both its children must be black )

i think that i must add a continue statement  in CASE 2 ...

Comment: I have no idea about this book, but a thing to bear in mind is that pseudocode tends to have mistakes because it can't be tested effectively. You might do better studying a tested implementation.  I've always like Ben Pfaff's library, which is written in C Web, the old literate programming system. See https://adtinfo.org/ . The PDF form is beautiful and fun to read.  There's a couple variations on Red Black trees there.

Comment: _i think that i must add a continue statement in CASE 2._
 You do. CASE 2 resumes the while loop with the parent as the new node to fixup.
Now there is a new parent, new sibling, new sibling's children.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this an "answer", but rather a suggestion.

Having implementing a RB tree library, I can assure you that the deletion algorithm is a bona-fide PITA. There's a ton of special cases and you need to understand (on paper) before attempting to implement in any language. Not to be disrespectful, but I highly doubt anyone will be willing to find your bugs for you here for free.

That said, unless your goal is specifically the challenge of implementing an RB tree from scratch, I would strongly suggest to implement an AVL tree instead. You'll find that the algorithms are much simpler, and there is an easy symmetry between insertion and deletion which is not the case with RB trees. Furthermore, AVL tree has the same performance characteristics as an RB tree, so why torture yourself?

P.S. I sincerely hope that no student shall be assigned to implement an RB tree deletion!

P.P.S. You can get tree-like performance out of a skip list, which is dead simple to implement compared to RB tree or AVL tree.